# Mean value based on another column group

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (2000 rows, 5 columns):

```
    year  month  day  GroupBy_Day  
0   2013     11    6            3 
1   2013     11    7           10  
2   2013     11    8            4  
3   2013     11    9            4 
4   2013     11   10            4 
...
24  2013     12    1            5
25  2013     12    2            4
26  2013     12    3            5
27  2013     12    4            2
28  2013     12    5            7
29  2013     12    6            1
```

I already grouped my elements and got the count for each days (column GroupBy_Day). I need to get the mean count by day (e.g, for all days 6, we have a mean of (3+1)/2 = 2 occurence), and substract this value to GroupBy_Day in a new column.

Comment: Your sample doesn't match your figures (or I fail understanding how you get `3, 10, ...` in `GroupBy_Day` , and how you get a mean of 11.8).

Comment: `df['GroupBy_Day'] - df['GroupBy_Day'].mean()`?

Comment: @jeanrjc I have 2000 more lines, not showed here. `day` is the day of the month, so I have a lot of day 6 with a corresponding value in GroupBy_Day. @Alexander I don't need the mean on all the columns, I need the mean for each value of day . I will change my example dataframe as it is misleading

Comment: `a.join(a.groupby('day')['GroupBy_Day'].mean().reset_index(), rsuffix='_mean', on='day')` (assuming the dataframe is a, of course) - is this what you need?

Comment: Yes! Thank you, can you post your answer ?